# Lucene Spans: How are the Positions Useful?

Tags: lucene

Lucene `Spans` objects have `startPosition()` and `endPosition()` methods, which, according to their [Javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/Spans.html) return "position[s] in the current doc." How are these useful?

My understanding is that these positions are the indices of the start and end tokens of the span—indices after an `Analyzer` has processed the original text. But after digging around Javadocs for awhile, I don't know what I can do with these positions. It seems like I should be able to query a document and, say, get the tokens between `startPosition` and `endPosition`, or maybe get the `offset`s corresponding to the positions, but I don't see anything like that.

How can I relate these positions back to the original text?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps span positions are only useful for search queries. From [Lucene Javadocs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html): "phrase and proximity searches rely on position info."